# How to get a wall of picture from different size with exact same width & height?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an image wall consisting of house photos.
 
The problem is : All of them are of different height and width. 
So, How can I use css to make all images look the same size? 
Here is my actual css ! With this, they all have the same width but not the same height :

```
.property-thumb-info, .property-thumb-info-image, .pgl-team-item .img-thumbnail-medium {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.property-thumb-info-image img, .pgl-team-item .img-thumbnail-medium img {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% + 50px);
  width: calc(100% + 50px);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0) scale(1.1);
  transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0) scale(1.1);
}

.pgl-property:hover .property-thumb-info-image img, .pgl-team-item:hover .img-thumbnail-medium img {
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1.1);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) scale(1.1);
}
```

And here is my html code :

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 animation">
  <div class="pgl-property">
    <div class="property-thumb-info">
      <div class="property-thumb-info-image" style="">
        <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="aze.png">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: set the `max-width` and `max-height` properties of the images.

Comment: It depends on your use case: would you like to crop the sides off, then make the images 100% height, if you would like to stretch the images, type witdth and height 100%

Comment: @Steven The best case will be to crop in the center of the picture for exemple. I want to keep proportions and the max size of my div. It's new for me, sorry for that !

Comment: @Berdesdan max-height did the trick for the big one, but not the tiny ones !

Comment: You seem to want `<img>` to behave like `background-image` with `background-size:cover;`. Why not use background images instead? `object-fit` doesn't have support in IE at all and in Edge only from v16 up.

Comment: @Pablo DelaNoche You will have issues with the smaller images if you are enlarging them.  Your images should all be the same size or bigger than the dimensions for your div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object-fit: cover` should do the trick.

Make all `img` element the same size and then:

```
.property-thumb-info-image img, .pgl-team-item .img-thumbnail-medium img 
{
   /* your code */
   object-fit: cover;
   /* your code */
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

Comment: watch out for support on this method.  See comment from @Andrei Gherghui on your post above  https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit